# Shopify API: How to load a content from 3rd party server into Shopify's store during the page load?

Tags: api, shopify, remote-server, schema.org

I'm building a Shopify's app which suppose to add Schema.org rich snippets according to data which is remotely stored on my server. In order that Google's crawler will actually analyze this snippets, they must be loaded during the page load, and not dynamically by some JavaScript.

Any suggestions if / how can I do something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [modifying an existing theme](http://api.shopify.com/theme.html) on their documentation page.

You could also try [assets](http://api.shopify.com/asset.html), based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932861/can-shopify-app-automatically-inject-liquid-code-inside-shops-theme/13936306#13936306).

Comment: The data on my server is dynamic, which means that if I want to use assets to modify themes, than every time that the data is changing I would need to call Shopify's API. In addition, the data is different for every Product, but there is only one liquid file for product. So I would have to inject all products data into the product.liquid and add a 'switch/case' inside the liquid. I thought about this before, but I felt that it's probably not the best practice.

Comment: Maybe check out the App Proxy mention in that answer - past that I think you might be out of luck.

Comment: From what I've read in Shopify's documentation, App Proxy is good for adding new pages to the store under the same domain, not modifying existing ones. Am I right?

Comment: It seems that way - but if you were to make it so that instead of loading the default product pages they loaded your (proxied) pages, you could get your content into the page on the load.

Comment: Interesting... The things that bothers me is that I'll have to override all the links to the product page in all the template files. Is there any easy way to do it?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, other than modifying their theme.

Comment: Be aware that if you choose to run your shop off the App Proxy, your shop will only function as fast as your proxy. So, if you have a busy shop, you best be having a muthatrucking fast server.

Comment: I'm still looking for alternative solution - there must be something else that we are missing. @girasquid thanks for your help anyway!